# How to set the symbol group list of lists to generate the random password using Python?

Tags: python, random

I am generating random password using `random` library following example 8 of [this page](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/1497/random.SystemRandom'). Here I am setting a default value for `symbolgroups` which contains all type characters in a single string. The code looks like this:

```
def get_random_string(length=20, symbolgroups="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*():<>/|}{[]`\`"):
    if length is None:
        length = CONF.password_length

    r = random.SystemRandom()
    password = [r.choice(s) for s in symbolgroups]
    r.shuffle(password)
    password = password[:length]
    length -= len(password)
    symbols = ''.join(symbolgroups)
    password.extend([r.choice(symbols) for _i in xrange(length)])
    r.shuffle(password)

    return ''.join(password)


rand = get_random_string()
print(rand)
```

The code produces a random password, but I am being told that I am using `symbolgroups` incorrectly.

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is? I'm trying to figure out what you mean by _but here I need The expected value `forsymbolgroups` is a list of lists, not a string._

Comment: I don't really understand your code. What for example is the line `password = [r.choice(s) for s in symbolgroups]` for -- why not just `[s for s in symbolgroups]`, or even just `list(symbolgroups)`?

Comment: means here `symbolgroups="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*():<>/|}{[]`"`  this is a string vale which should be a list.

Comment: `password = [r.choice(s) for s in symbolgroups]
print(password)` this gives me the output `['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', ':', '<', '>', '/', '|', '}', '{', '[', ']', '`', '\\', '`']`

Comment: yes thats true.

Comment: @satya for the way that you’re using `symbolgroups`, it doesn’t matter if it’s a list or a str. You’ll get the same result.

Comment: Your code shouldn't require `symbolgroups` to be a list (you're indexing into `symbolgroups` which works for strings like it would for lists). If I run your code I get output that looks like `\4f5#oqz19s|g&d(}{^@`.

Comment: @birryree : I know it but can you please take a look what my client gives the comment on it ?

Comment: @birryree : `import random
symbolgroups="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*():<>/|}{[]`\`"
r = random.SystemRandom()
password = [r.choice(s) for s in symbolgroups]
password
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', ':', '<', '>', '/', '|', '}', '{', '[', ']', '`', '\\', '`']`.How is that a random password? The expected value for symbolgroups is a list of lists, not a string.

Comment: It seems like what you've posted above and what you're asking about are two different pieces of code. The code in your question does not generate that kind of output.

Comment: @birryree : That was my full code but he comments by reading the half of the code.

Comment: So you have a client who's questioning half the behavior of your code? It seems like your client doesn't know what the code should be generating, especially if they apparently think it's going to generate a list containing your exact string.

Comment: It’s not our responsibility to help you deal with what ***your*** client commented, the code you posted above works (with the exception that there’s some unnecessary code). You will need to tell your client to use the complete code that you posted.

Comment: Adding to what @abccd and @ThomasKuhn has said - you do some extraneous stuff that is unnecessary. `password = [r.choice(s) for s in symbolgroups]` (as you're talking about) seems completely useless - wouldn't your code just be simplified to `password = ''.join(random.choice(symbol_groups) for _ in xrange(length))`? I don't really understand why you do all the extra stuff (you rebind `password` multiple times and do a lot of throwaway computation). Also, if you're generating passwords (for apparently client code), why not use a real solution like `libsodium`?

Comment: Can you post your stuff so that it will generate the random number ?

Comment: @birryree : Can you please take a look example-8  of this 'https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/1497/random.SystemRandom'  link. What should be the `DEFAULT_PASSWORD_SYMBOLS`.

Comment: Why didn't you right away say that you took that code from somewhere else, where it is also properly commented. The idea is most likely that you should have a character from several groups of characters, like numbers, lower case letters, upper case letters, and others. In this case your `symbolgroups` would indeed be a list. Something like `['ABC','abc','123','^%&']`.

Comment: @ThomasKühn : Can you please modify this by using your idea ? I think you are right.

Comment: I edited the question quite extensively in order to hopefully make it more understandable.

Comment: @ThomasKühn: re your edit, please don't add "can someone help me" to questions here - we think [it isn't a very useful addition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: @halfer ok, I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code given in the question actually comes from example 8 on [this page](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/1497/random.SystemRandom') where it is also properly documented. There is nothing wrong with the code and it is also not bloated as we first believed in the comments. The only problem was that the OP misunderstood the use of `symbolgroups`. Here the idea was to guarantee that the final password contains one character of each character group defined in `symbolgroups`. If instead of the original, the default value for `symbolgroups` is changed into a list, the code should work as expected. For instance, we could group the list of characters into lower case letters,  numbers, and others:

```
def get_random_string(length=20, symbolgroups=["0123456789","abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz","!@#$%^&*():<>/|}{[]`\`"]):
    if length is None:
        length = CONF.password_length

    r = random.SystemRandom()
    password = [r.choice(s) for s in symbolgroups]
    r.shuffle(password)
    password = password[:length]
    length -= len(password)
    symbols = ''.join(symbolgroups)
    password.extend([r.choice(symbols) for _i in xrange(length)])
    r.shuffle(password)

    return ''.join(password)
```

This gives really nice example results:

```
^9m0bj83u<h7j^i:^e!}
```